# MvcScaffolding creates disposable resources that are not disposed

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, idisposable, dbcontext, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Using MvcScaffolding with EF4.1, I see that the first generated line of a Controller generally is the following field definition:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private BarContext context = new BarContext();
    //.....
```

where `BarContext` is as follows:

```
 public class BarContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
```

Given that `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` implements `IDisposable`, I am surprised not to find any generated override in `FooController` for the `Dispose(bool)` method that might take care of disposing `context`.

Is this an oversight in the templates, or is there something I'm missing that makes this a non-issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything, you do need to override Dispose, as described in this EF tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application
The built-in scaffolding in MVC 3 Tools Update does generate the override (pre-release versions did not but the released version does), as noted in the tutorial. If the NuGet MvcScaffolding package does not do it, that is an oversight.